Django profiling threads? / optimisation
I've got two simple applications in django. Only running one of them (ie. openning in a browser), creates 47 threads on hosting server. While trying to run the second one, I've got already hosting error- because of threads limitations...
Bash error is:
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 7 of 48: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 500 current, 500 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 8 of 48: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 500 current, 500 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 9 of 48: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 500 current, 500 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 10 of 48: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 500 current, 500 max
The question is - is it possible somehow to limit it in django application, or am I able somehow to find places in django code I'm doing something wrong??
Is it normal, that simple django operations like - login ,or db querying, or displaying output via template create 47 threads?
Hmm looking at bash, and htop,
I've got around 40-50 processess:
/home/username/env/bin/python/opt/passenger/src/helper/wsgi-loader.py
is it normal and ok?
ps. should i have 2 separate virtualenv for each one, or should they work in one virtualenv on server?

What exactly is running that creates 47 threads?

I don't know. It's not my intentional code. I'm not using any threading in my code. It is just internals of django... but I don't know how/why/where.    All I was able to do so far was to add in my code:
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'    what helped....    but again - I do not know the root cause of the problem

If you are using NumPY, NumPY uses OpenBLAS and OpenBLAS can use over 1000 threads if need be so if you don’t want that, then limiting to say 32 will do. I don’t know if you are using NumPY but nonetheless, OpenBLAS is responsible.
